# Focus on input inside a component from outside that component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

The scenario is as follows, I have a component to upload files, but it looks really ugly (classic `input type="file"`), so I want to make an stylized label (maybe an image or something) that when you click it you get the same behavior as if you clicked the file input.

I managed to make this work by having the template of my `upload.component` inside the template I want to use, but since I need to upload files in many different places I don't want to have to duplicate code each time.

*This works just fine..*

```css
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
        <img src="placeholder.jpg"/>
    </label>

    <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
</div>
```

*This does not..*

```html
<!-- my-other.component.html -->
<label for="file-input">
    <img src="placeholder.jpg"/>
</label>
<app-upload></app-upload>

<!-- upload.component.html -->
<input id="file-input" type="file" />
```

So is there a way to reference an input that is "enclosed" inside a component?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what I did was

CSS:

```
#file{
    position: absolute; 
    top: -100vh;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file">
<a onclick="select_file()" id="file_button">File</a>
```

jQuery JS:

```
function select_file(){
    $('#file').click();
}
```

I think you can do it with vanilla JS but I already included jQuery in my project so whatever...
and the element with onclick doesn't have to be a link